# How to load image based on range value that contain url path location?

Tags: excel, vba

I have got the code to insert some pictures in the table as shown in the image below.

[image]

The code to display the image is as follows

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Const PW As String = "222"
Dim sPictures, sPic, PhotoCell() As Variant, pic As Shape
Dim PictCell As Range
Dim fname As String
Dim x As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet


PhotoCell() = Array("G4:J7", "C9:E13", "H9:J13", "C14:E18", "H14:J18 ")
sPictures = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
   "Pictures (*.jpeg; *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png), *.jpeg; *.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif", 0 , _
   "Select Photo", "OK", MultiSelect:=True)

x = 0
If IsArray(sPictures) Then
    ws.Unprotect PW
    For Each sPic In sPictures
        
        Set PictCell = ActiveSheet.Range(PhotoCell(x))
        x = x + 1
        RemovePicsInRange PictCell 'delete any existing shape in this range
        
        With ws.Shapes.AddPicture(sPic, msoFalse, msoCTrue, 0, 0, 100, 100)
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Height = PictCell.Height - 5
            .Width = PictCell.Width - 5
            .Top = PictCell.Top + 2
            .Left = PictCell.Left + 2
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
    PictCell.Value = sPic
    Next sPic
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=PW
Else
    MsgBox "Cancelled!"
End Sub
```

The problem is, when the file accommodates many pictures, the file size becomes large. To solve that problem, I removed the image object and replaced it with image url path via BeforeClose Event.

So far I have tried different code to re-display the image but nothing works.

One of the codes I've tried is the following

```
Sub LoadPicture()
Dim Tab1, Tab2, MyTab As Range
'to summarize the code, I wrote only tab1 and tab2, actually I have up to tab20
Set Tab1 = Range("G4:J7, C9:E13, H9:J13, C14:E18, H14:J18 ")
Set Tab2 = Range("G23:J26, C28:E32, H28:J32, C33:E37, H33:J37 ")
Set MyTab = Union(Tab1, Tab2)
MyTab.Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert MyTab.Value
End Sub
```

So, is there a way to display those images based on url path value with one click?

Comment: All the steps you need to import the images are in the first code you posted, except you're reading the path from the sheet and not asking the user to choose files.

Comment: The method I want to implement is: (1) I ask the user to enter the images along with the path value (it's in the first code). (2) When the user closes the workbook, the images will be deleted (I inserted the code to delete the images in the `BeforeClose Event)` without removing the path value in each range. (3) This is my question: when the workbook is re-opened, I need a code to load the whole image based on the path value in each range with a single click (so far I have tried several codes and it never worked. One of the best code concise I've tried is in the second code in the post)

Comment: Look at the steps in the first code though - you need to set the position and size for each picture.  You could almost re-run the first code, with the only difference being if there's a path in the range then use that and don't ask the user to pick files.

Comment: Yes, those individual ranges are merged. I've already set the position and size. But even the second code doesn't work at all. The code does not display the image even in any size and in any position. In essence, the second code in the post failed to load any images.

Comment: It doesn't work because it *can't* work - you need to import and size each image individually: there's no support for your "all at once" approach.

Comment: oh i think there is something i can do. but, thanks for the explanation, william.